# Python 3: Slice a dynamic array that contains n number of elements, beginning with a starting index

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I am attempting to return a dynamic array that contains n # of elements from the original array starting with the element requested at `start_index`

This method fails testing stating the size of the dynamic array is incorrect.

```
    def slice(self, start_index: int, size: int) -> "DynamicArray":  
        slice_array = DynamicArray()
        if(start_index < 0) or (start_index >= self._size):
            raise DynamicArrayException
        elif(size > self._size) or (size + start_index >= self._size) or (size < 0):
            raise DynamicArrayException

        #resize to fit the number of elements
        for i in range(start_index, size+start_index):
            slice_array.append(self._data[i])
        return DynamicArray()
```

What I have written to me means if the start index does not fit in the range of the self.size then an exception is raised. If the start index fits within the range a new dynamic array would be created called `slice_array` with the elements starting at `start_index` through the rest of the original array.

I'm not sure what is wrong here. I would assume `size + start_index` would set the size of the new dynamic array but that's not what is happening.

Comment: In the last line of the function, do you mean to `return slice_array` rather than `return DynamicArray()`?

Comment: @slothrop yes I did and now I feel silly for posting this. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Slothrop, I am returning the wrong object. I should have been returning the created slice_array in the last line of the function